# Web Scraping - how to extract stock price

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

I am creating a web scraping python code (using 2.7.11) that extracts the stock price using symbol. I am not sure why this is not working. But it gives me this output:

```
Enter Financial Symbol

appl YPE h
Do you want to run again?
```

My code is below:

```
import urllib

go=True

while go:
    print "Enter Financial Symbol"
    symbol=raw_input()

    page=urllib.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" + symbol)

    text=page.read()
    where=text.find("yfs_l84")
  
    start=where+7
    end=start+5

    result = text[start:end]
    print ( symbol + " "+ result)


    print "Do you want to run again?"
    choice=raw_input()
    if choice == "no":
        go=False
```

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The string `"yfs_l84"` you are searching for is not contained in the HTML returned by yahoo. So

```
where=text.find("yfs_l84")
```

leaves `where` to be `-1`. So your slice `text[start:end]` will always be `text[6:11]` and cut `YPR h` out of the page source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using str.find to parse a webpage, you should use an html parser like [bs4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) but in this case there is an api that you can requests the data from in json format, combining with [requests](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) makes it pretty trivial to get the data.

```
In [25]: import  requests

In [26]: sym = "DVN"    
In [27]: r = requests.get("http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/{sym}/quote?format=json".format(sym=sym)) 
In [28]: r.json()
Out[28]: 
{'list': {'meta': {'count': 1, 'start': 0, 'type': 'resource-list'},
  'resources': [{'resource': {'classname': 'Quote',
     'fields': {'name': 'Devon Energy Corporation Common',
      'price': '18.650000',
      'symbol': 'DVN',
      'ts': '1455915714',
      'type': 'equity',
      'utctime': '2016-02-19T21:01:54+0000',
      'volume': '33916489'}}}]}}

In [29]: sym = "YHOO"
In [30]: r = requests.get("http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/{sym}/quote?format=json".format(sym=sym))
In [31]: r.json()
Out[31]: 
{'list': {'meta': {'count': 1, 'start': 0, 'type': 'resource-list'},
  'resources': [{'resource': {'classname': 'Quote',
     'fields': {'name': 'Yahoo! Inc.',
      'price': '30.040001',
      'symbol': 'YHOO',
      'ts': '1455915600',
      'type': 'equity',
      'utctime': '2016-02-19T21:00:00+0000',
      'volume': '20734985'}}}]}}

In [32]: sym = "AAPL"
In [33]: r = requests.get("http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/{sym}/quote?format=json".format(sym=sym))
In [34]: r.json()
Out[34]: 
{'list': {'meta': {'count': 1, 'start': 0, 'type': 'resource-list'},
  'resources': [{'resource': {'classname': 'Quote',
     'fields': {'name': 'Apple Inc.',
      'price': '96.040001',
      'symbol': 'AAPL',
      'ts': '1455915600',
      'type': 'equity',
      'utctime': '2016-02-19T21:00:00+0000',
      'volume': '35374173'}}}]}}
```

You can pull whatever data you want using accessing by key which is a lot more robust than str.find.