# Python Failed with KeyError

Tags: python, dictionary, populate

```
def getQuotesYahoo():

    tickerStr = "GOOGL+AMZN"
    yahoo_url ="http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=%s&f=saohgb3t1" % (tickerStr)
    retQuotes = {}

    data = urllib2.urlopen(yahoo_url).readlines()

    for d in data:
        p = d.strip().split(',')
        stkInfo = {}
        stkInfo['lastTime'] = p[6]
        stkInfo['last'] = p[1]
        stkInfo['open'] = p[2]
        stkInfo['high'] = p[3]
        stkInfo['low'] = p[4]
        stkInfo['bid'] = p[5]
        tic = p[0]
        print stkInfo
        retQuotes[tic] = stkInfo

    print retQuotes['GOOGL']['last']
```

This code fails on KeyError and not populating dictionary with string key.  I have basically same code working for googlefiance.

> KeyError: 'GOOGL'
>
> retQuotes:
>
> {'"AMZN"': {'last': '594.60', 'bid': 'N/A', 'high': '597.86', 'low': '589.00', 'lastTime': '"4:00pm"', 'open': '594.32'}, '"GOOGL"': {'last': '759.98', 'bid': 'N/A', 'high': '767.13', 'low': '755.77', 'lastTime': '"4:00pm"', 'open': '765.87'}}

Comment: the stock ticker for google isn't `GOOGL`, it's `GOOG`

Comment: What ends up in `retQuotes`? Printing the variable could be helpful.

Comment: looks like ticker is in the structure.

Comment: it seems the key present in the dict is `'"GOOGL"'` so there are double quotes in the key. (The whole string is actually `"GOOGL"`)

Comment: ticker is GOOGL and GOOG

Comment: ahh.. ic just need to clean the quotes up.  thanks guys

Comment: You can get  json back using the api http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541017/web-scraping-code-to-extract-stock-price/35541497#35541497 so you are somewhat reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems the key present in the dict is '"GOOGL"' so there are double quotes in the key. (The whole string is actually "GOOGL") so you would need to refer to it as:

```
retQuotes['"GOOGL"']['last']
```

Although it looks like (with the exception of `N/A`) all the data from the stock would be valid python literals, which means you can use `ast.literal_eval` to parse the data as a tuple:

```
d = d.replace("N/A","None")
fields = ast.literal_eval("(%s)"%d) #add round brackets to indicate the data is a tuple
```

You can also shorten the declaration by using `zip` with the `dict` constructor:

```
import ast
field_names = ('last','open','high','low','bid','lastTime')
for d in data:
    d = d.replace("N/A","None")
    fields = ast.literal_eval("(%s)"%d) #add round brackets to indicate the data is a tuple
    stock = fields[0]
    stkInfo = dict(zip(field_names,fields[1:]))
    retQuotes[stock] = stkInfo
```

Comment: I would think this would be much faster as well.  Thanks for the help

Comment: @user3763220 Please know there is a mechanism for [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).